# How to fetch a Paginated Tuple with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch records from two tables with a union in a paginated manner so my code looks like follows

```
@Query(value = "select topup_date_time as date_time, topup_notes as description, credit_amount as amount, credit_currency as currency, 'CREDIT' as type, cardholder_code\n" +
        "from\n" +
        "payment_card.topup \n" +
        "where\n" +
        "cardholder_code = :cardholderCode and topup_date_time > :fromDateTime and topup_date_time < :toDateTime \n" +
        "union all\n" +
        "select requested_at, withdrawal_note, amount, currency, 'DEBIT', cardholder_code\n" +
        "from\n" +
        "payment_card.withdrawal \n" +
        "where\n" +
        "cardholder_code = :cardholderCode and requested_at > :fromDateTime and requested_at < :toDateTime \n" +
        "-- #pageable\n",
        countQuery = "select count(*) from ( select cardholder_code from payment_card.topup where cardholder_code = :cardholderCode and topup_date_time > :fromDateTime and topup_date_time < :toDateTime \n" +
                "union all\n" +
                "select cardholder_code from payment_card.withdrawal where cardholder_code = :cardholderCode and requested_at > :fromDateTime and requested_at < :toDateTime ) as un",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Page<Tuple> getTopupAndWithdrawalByCardholderCodeWithDateFilter(UUID cardholderCode, LocalDateTime fromDateTime, LocalDateTime toDateTime, Pageable pageable);
```

And i am mapping this into a DTO as follows

```
pagedResult.get().map(t->t.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And this throws me an exception

```
Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Object javax.persistence.Tuple.get(int) is no accessor method!
```

If I return List from the JPA method. It works, but I want the records in pagination and I want the total records too, so don't want to go through SQL query pagination and a separate query to count.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that Spring Data JPA is not able to infer that a native query result can use `Tuple` as result type, but you should be able to use `Object[]`.